# Hyperledger Fabric response: status:500 message:"failed to execute transaction timeout expired while executing transaction"

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger

I am facing this issue and wanted to ask if someone knows what it could be. chaincode is installed and invoked

```
peer chaincode query -o orderer.example.com:7050 --tls --cafile $ORDERER_CA -C mychannel -n bachelortest -c '{"Args":["getTransactionPriv","1"]}'
```

> error: endorsement failure during query. response: status:500 message:"failed to execute transaction 11254006859fbd102ec468c4100b18a1241445a0c066280ca81510485d43a93f: error sending: timeout expired while executing transaction"

Comment: Can you please add the logs of orderer and peers?

Comment: Where can i find the logs?

Comment: If you want to see the logs of your ``orderer`` container, go in your terminal and use command ``docker logs orderer.example.com``